# Firebase get grandchildren by id

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I have a very simple structure where I have a collection `teachers`.

There are multiple `teachers` and each `teacher` has multiple `students`.
Every student has multiple `invoices`.

How can I retreive all `invoices` of `students` being children of a teacher?
Is it even possible?

I am coming from a SQL background which makes my head twist when looking at how Firebase does some things. But I guess that's due to the inexperience with NO-SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're using firestore and going to assume the following structure:

"teachers" collection that contains list of teachers as documents

each teacher will have
"students" sub-collection that contains list of students as documents

each student will have
"invoices" sub-collection that contains list of students as documents

For a **specific invoice** for a **specific student** of a specific teacher:

```
db.collection("teachers").doc(teacherUID)
.collection("students").doc(studentUid)
.collection("invoices").doc(invoiceUid)
.get().then(function(doc) {
if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
} else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
}}).catch(function(error) {
console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

For **all invoices** for a **specific student** of a specific teacher:

```
db.collection("teachers").doc(teacherUID)
.collection("students").doc(studentUid)
.collection("invoices")
.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (invoice) {
        console.log(invoice.id, ' => ', invoice.data());
    }});
```

Now, for a **specific invoice** of a **all students** for a specific teacher:

first query for all students, then get a specific invoice or query for all invoices like shown above;

```
db.collection("teachers").doc(teacherUID)
.collection("students")
.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (student) {
      console.log(student.id, ' => ', student.data());

      //ToDo: get the student's invoice/s
      }});
```

Comment: Thank you, your assumptions are correct.
That means though, that in your last example I need to get all students. No possibility to only get only the invoices without all the student data, right?

Comment: @j.Doe you can get the invoices directly if you know the studentsId;
you can save the students ids in an array list in the teachers document (this will be cheaper since you don't have to get charged for retrieving all students documents)